# Angular 6 Promise

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, angular6

I am trying to call a file controller inside the component file, the controller returns a value which is avaliable inside the file but is undefined in the caller function, which is a JS threading issue, so I am trying to solve it via promise but I am new with Promise and its not going well, Please go through two files and tell me where I went wrong.

My Component file :

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Meta, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { BaseComponent } from '../core/base.component';
import { MetaData } from '../core/interfaces/Meta';
import { HomeService } from './home.service';
import { CarouselOptions, CarouselData } from '../shared/components/carousel/interface/Carousel';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Utility } from '../core/utility';
import { ConfigurationService } from '../configuration/configuration.service';
import { PreloaderService } from '../shared/components/preloader/preloader.service';
import { InfiniteScrollModule } from 'ngx-infinite-scroll';
import { HomeController } from './home-controller';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  railsData: CarouselData[]; // Rails data.
  railOptions: CarouselOptions; // Rails options.
  railIds: Array<string> = []; // Rail Ids.
  railsSubscription: Subscription;
  pageType: string;
  backgroundColor: string; // Page background color.
  backgroundImage: string;
  railServiceData;
  railInfo;
  railControlledDatas;



  constructor(meta: Meta, title: Title, private route: ActivatedRoute, public homeService: HomeService
    , public utility: Utility, public configurationService: ConfigurationService,
    private preloaderService: PreloaderService, private InfiniteScrollModule: InfiniteScrollModule,
    private homeController: HomeController) {
    super(meta, title); // Call base component

    // Initialise the variables.
    this.railsData = [];
    this.railOptions = {};
    this.pageType = 'home';
    // Set the Title & Description.
    const metaData: MetaData = { author: 'Attinad', keywords: 'template, app', description: 'My description' };
    this.setMetaData(metaData, 'Home');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.pageType = params['type'] ? params['type'] : 'home';

      // Apply theme.
      if (this.configurationService.themeConfig && this.configurationService.themeConfig.theme_json) {
        const homeTheme = JSON.parse(this.configurationService.themeConfig.theme_json).landingPage;

        this.backgroundColor = homeTheme.bgColor ? homeTheme.bgColor : ''; // Background color.
        this.backgroundImage = this.configurationService.getAssetByKey(homeTheme.bgImage) ?
          this.configurationService.getAssetByKey(homeTheme.bgImage) : ''; // Background Image.
      }
      // Scroll to the page top postion.
      this.utility.scrollToTop();

      // Fetch and display the rails.
      // setTimeout(() => {
        this.displayRails(this.pageType);
      // }, 1000);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // Clear the rail count variable in the service.
    this.homeService.clearRails();

    // Unsubscribe the observables.
    if (this.railsSubscription) {
      this.railsSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

  /**
   * @description method to display the rails.
   * @returns - Observable SessionResponse
   */
  displayRails(pageType: string): void {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.preloaderService.show();
 
        this.railControlledDatas = this.homeController.getRailController(pageType);
        console.log('k',this.railControlledDatas);
     
        this.preloaderService.hide();
      return promise
    }
  }

  /**
   * @description sample method for handling lazy loading scroll down event
   * @returns void
   */
  onScrollDown(): void {
    // Call the next set of rails while scrolling.
    // And avoid the error while clicking back button setTimeout added.(Lazy Loading issue)
    setTimeout(() => this.displayRails(this.pageType), 1000);
  }
}
```

My Controller File

```js
import { HomeTransformation } from './home-transformation'
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { RailsData, RailDataAll } from './interfaces/homeTranformation';
import { CarouselOptions, CarouselData } from '../shared/components/carousel/interface/Carousel';
import { HomeService } from './home.service';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

@Injectable()
export class HomeController {
    railsData: CarouselData[]; // Rails data.
    railOptions: CarouselOptions; // Rails options.
    railIds: Array<string> = []; // Rail Ids.
    homeData: RailDataAll[];
    homeServices;
    railSubscription;
    railInfo;
    railsSubscription;
    constructor(private transformObj: HomeTransformation, private homeService: HomeService) {
        this.railsData = null;

    }
    /**
      * @description Accepts data from api and feeds to Transformation
      * @returns homeData
      */
    // servicedata = this.server();
    // transformdsata
    // = this.transformObj(serverifd);return trandda;
    getRailController(pageType): RailDataAll[] {

       
            this.railsSubscription = this.homeService.getRails(pageType).subscribe((data: CarouselData[]) => {
                // Concat the new and old rail data.
                data = { ...this.railsData, ...data };

                // Get the keys from the rails object.
                this.railIds = Object.keys(data);
                // Append the railoption to every rail.
                this.railIds.map((railId: string) => {
                    this.railInfo = this.homeService.getRailInfo(railId); // Get the rail info for corresponding rail id.
                    data[railId].railOptions = this.homeService.getRailOptions(this.railInfo); // Get the rails options.  
                    // console.log(data);
                });
                // Assign data to the rails.
                this.railsData = data;
                console.log(this.railsData);
                this.homeData = this.transformObj.transformgetRails(this.railsData);
                console.log(this.homeData);
            });

            return this.homeData;

        };

    }
```

Comment: looks like your `displayRails` has a misplaced return (why would you return promise inside the new promise executor function) and a Promise that is never resolved or rejected (what do you think those arguments to Promise constructor are for?)

Comment: This is my first experiment with promise, I usually go for Observables.

Comment: Can you edit in answers

Comment: nope, can't begin to imagine what your code *should* be doing with that promise ... when will it resolve, or reject? why return any value at all, since it's totally disregarded by the calling code?

Comment: Actually you see the function doesnt wait for the API response , hence it executes with empty data.

Comment: Is this even the current syntax of promise?

Comment: no, you are not using Promise at all well ... refer to some Promise tutorial for guidance

Answer (score 1):

If your more accustomed to work with Observable than Promise, then try the Observable.fromPromise like this:

```
let myPromise = getSomePromise();
let myObservable = Observable.fromPromise(myPromise);
```

From what I see in your example, your return statement is misplaced. You do not even need any Promise and should do something like below.

In your controller file :

```
getRailController(pageType): Observable<RailDataAll[]> {

            return this.homeService.getRails(pageType).pipe(mergeMap((data: CarouselData[]) => {

                // Concat the new and old rail data.
                data = { ...this.railsData, ...data };

                // Get the keys from the rails object.
                this.railIds = Object.keys(data);

                // Append the railoption to every rail.
                this.railIds.map((railId: string) => {
                    this.railInfo = this.homeService.getRailInfo(railId); // Get the rail info for corresponding rail id.
                    data[railId].railOptions = this.homeService.getRailOptions(this.railInfo); // Get the rails options.  
                    // console.log(data);
                });

                // Assign data to the rails.
                this.railsData = data;
                console.log(this.railsData);
                this.homeData = this.transformObj.transformgetRails(this.railsData);
                console.log(this.homeData);

                return of(this.homeData);
            });

        }
```

In your component file :

```
displayRails(pageType: string): void {

      this.preloaderService.show();

        this.homeController.getRailController(pageType).subscribe(
        data => {
           this.railControlledDatas = data
           console.log('k',this.railControlledDatas);
           this.preloaderService.hide();
        });
    }
```

Comment: I am getting few errors in this implementation @rguerin

Comment: ERROR in src/app/home/home-controller.ts(39,52): error TS2339: Property 'flatMap' does not exist on type 'Observable<CarouselData[]>'.
src/app/home/home-controller.ts(57,13): error TS2322: Type 'RailDataAll[]' is not assignable to type 'Observable<RailDataAll[]>'.
  Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'RailDataAll[]'.
src/app/home/home-controller.ts(60,31): error TS2339: Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.

Comment: Which version of RxJs and typescript are you using ? Did you import well the Observabe lib (import { Observable } from 'rxjs';) ?

Comment: rxjs 6 ts 2.9 , yes I did

Comment: Do you also have the RxJs compat package ? Try "npm i rxjs-compat --save"

Comment: No I Migrated the application from 5 using compat and removed It after updating

Comment: Then either keep the  rxjs-compat or adapt this code using the new RxJs syntax (it  will take more time). You can find it there : https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/of.html. This is just a syntax/lib issue, you have your answer about the algorithmic part ;)

Comment: I edited my first post to be compliant with the last version of rxjs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182729/discussion-between-rguerin-and-v5nxt).